# Youtube API liveChat messages Quota Limit way too low

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am implementing an application that should react to live chat messages.

In a first test I simply called `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages` to get the chats and author details (parameter `part=snippet,authorDetails`). The response indicates `pollingIntervalMillis: 1000` so in theory I could call the API every second. However my little manual testing (without automated polling) already used a stunning 120 Quota Usage out of a 10.000 daily limit?

Am I doing something wrong?

Will I get lower usage if I specify something like a `fields` parameter to only ask for the needed data (message text + author name)?

I have the feeling to have missed some important thing to cut down the quota usage? Or is this simply not a supported use case?

Is there something like a streaming API that pushes new messages to my server?

Comment: I tested today the exact quota usage for one API call to the `messages` endpoint. With an added fields parameter to only return: `nextPageToken, items(snippet(displayMessage), authorDetails(channelId,displayName,profileImageUrl)` i get "billed" 8 quota usage points :(